# How to find the coordinates (lat & long) in a radius (say like 10 meters) from a given lat & long coordinate using google maps JS api

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-maps-api-3

I've a polyLine on click of which i need to change its color & change the color of the surrounding (say like 10 meters) polyLines to blue color. On click of other polyLine i need to make that as green & need to revert to red for the pervious clicked polyline.

I'm able to change the color of the polyline clicked & revert to its original red color on click of other **but how to find out the surrounding polylines which lies in radius like 10 meters of selected Polyline.**

Below is my code:

```
let polylines = [];
var prev_path;
let poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: latlng_array,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        strokeColor: 'red',
        object_id: feature.id
    });
    poly.setMap(map);

poly.addListener('click', function(event) {
            this.setOptions({
                strokeColor: 'green'
            });
            if (prev_path) {
                prev_path.setOptions({
                    strokeColor: 'red'
                });
            }
            prev_path = this;
polylines.push(poly);
```

here is my Demo https://jsfiddle.net/hellraizer/2kt508yo/

Comment: Do you have some online demo?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/joseadrian/7492128 here is sample code

Comment: You might be able to use [isLocationOnEdge](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry#poly.isLocationOnEdge). Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip
i've added my demo

Comment: Is the radius of 10 meters from the clicked point?  Or from the clicked polyline?

Comment: @HellRaizzer can you check below my answer, updated https://jsfiddle.net/rf6y7mhz/ fiddle with your code

Comment: @geocodezip from clicked polyline

Comment: hi @geocodezip ,
how to send 10 meters as tolerance in degrees to isLocationOnEdge

Comment: @HellRaizzer check updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pgc9wx6e/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use [Helper function](https://gist.github.com/joseadrian/7492128) to detect intersection

`intersectsCircle` is helper function to detect intersection between `polyline` and `polyline`(with your radius)

**Edit**

Below fiddle with your code, It will set all lines with `yellow` if it is within `10m` radius otherwise `black`

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgc9wx6e/5/)

Below is logic to when you click on `Polyline` check near by `polyline` within `10m` radius.

```
var radius = 10;
  polylines.forEach((poly) => {

    if (poly.intersectsCircle(selectedpoly, radius)) {
      color = '#FF0';
    } else {
      color = '#000';
    }
    poly.setOptions({
      strokeColor: color
    });

  })

}
```